# Seemingly simple, practically impossible (?) CSS layout - take all vertical space

Tags: html, css

I've been trying for three days to create this seemingly simple CSS layout:

`___________________
|_________1________|
|              |   |
|              | 3 |
|      2       |   |
|              |___|
|              | 4 |
|______________|___|`

1 is a breadcrumb navigator, 100% width. Height will vary between 1 (laptop) and 3 (handheld with small screen) lines, so max-height: 3em; will do. Minimum height to fit content.

2 will contain an HTML5 or SWF virtual panorama. There is a javascript loader which fits it into the available space, so I need 2 to fill all available space after the other sections take theirs. This is what I'm having insane trouble with - to get it to fill all available vertical height. When I set height: 100% it makes vertical scrollbars appear because it doesn't take away the height of 1 from 100%.

3 contains a description of the panorama. It should be about 20% width and all available height once 4 takes its space. If the content of 3 is more than can be displayed, vertical scrollbars should appear, so overflow: auto; should do it.

4 contains just a few tags, so same width as 3 and max-height: 3em;, min height to fit content.

If possible, I want to avoid using display: table, unless there is no other way without making life really complicated. Absolutely no pixel units.

This is the closest I got to: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LosJx

Problems:

- 2 does not fill all available vertical space.
- 4 should always be visible even when there is a lot of content in 3. Currently it gets pushed out of view if you resize the window to a small size.
- if you increase the vertical window size, you will see 4 does not stick to the bottom of the screen. I guess display: fixed; is what I need, but then how do I get 3 to show scrollbars if it needs to?

The HTML structure is not strict, elements can be added or removed, but it would be nice if I didn't have to deviate too far from what is already there as I'll have to then get this to fit the existing pages.

I will keep trying, but would appreciate advice or mockups very much!

---

Update 2 hours later

Thank you everyone for answering! I will review your replies in detail.

In the meanwhile I kept trying, and this is what I came up with:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aunbz
No tables, no pixel dimensions, everything works as needed, except that the navigator does not span the entire length of the top as I'd like it to. Any method I tried to make it do so resulted in the 100% height of "2" not taking it into account, so a vertical scrollbar would appear.

I don't know about cross-browser support of this solution yet, I suppose the CSS table method would be safest in this regard.

Comment: You can put #3 and #4 inside of a new #5 container, and then make #4 a sticky footer inside the #5 container. Look up CSS Sticky Footer. That will solve your 2nd bullet point.

Comment: there doesn't exist something like display:fixed. i think you mean position:fixed. that means it stays at the position even if you scroll down the page, I don't know if you want that, if so, you should add position:fixed to #3 because #4 is inside of #3

Comment: Oops, yes I meant position: fixed

Answer (score 1):

You want the height of #2 to be based on the sum of #3 and #4 and at the same time the difference of 100% height - #1.  You will have to put it all into a table(or use display:table and display:table-cell on divs) or use javascript to resize divs based on the window height.

From what I think you want I have done up an embedded table layout using divs here: http://jsfiddle.net/3mX4r/

```
<style>
html{height:100%;}
body{height:100%;margin:0px;}
div#topCell1{display:table-cell;background-color:blue;}
div#bottomHalf{height:100%;}

div#left2{display:table-cell;background-color:red;height:100%;width:80%;}

div#rightCon{display:table-cell;height:100%;width:20%;}
div#right3{display:table-cell;background-color:gray;height:100%;}
div#right3Container{height:100%;width:100%;overflow:auto;}

div#right4{display:table-cell;background-color:black;}

div.table{display:table;height:100%;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
div.tableRow{display:table-row;}
</style>

<div id="mainContainer" class="table">
    <div class="tableRow">
        <div id="topCell1">
            &nbsp;<br>
            &nbsp;<br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomHalf" class="tableRow">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="tableRow">
                <div id="left2">

                </div>
                <div id="rightCon">
                    <div class="table">            
                        <div class="tableRow">
                            <div id="right3">
                                <div id="right3Container">
                                    &nbsp;<br>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tableRow">
                            <div id="right4">
                                &nbsp;<br>
                                &nbsp;<br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this layout http://karlwilhelm.bplaced.de/ ?

1. I recommend you to give the header a fixed height forever, for example 50px.
2. Put #3 and #4 into a container with `float:right` and is always visible with `position:fixed`.